# Installing spatstaton R studio

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, spatstat

I am attempting to upload the R package "spatstat" in R studio, and am reciceving the following warning message. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

> install.packages("spatst") Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mallarie/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘spatst’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize you spelled the package name wrong, right? Look at the name in the error message.

Comment: Did you verify the spelling of the package name? Your question indicates that you didn't.

Comment: Opps. Copied the wrong warning message. I did spell incorectly the first time, but repeated in and recieved this:> 

package ‘spatstat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\Mallarie\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\file266c1ca95dbb\spatstat’ to ‘C:\Users\Mallarie\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\spatstat’

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\Mallarie\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgLkPHa\downloaded_packages

Comment: @MallarieYeager, That sounds like insufficient permissions. Try running R as admin and then try installing. Search the error here on SO and you're likely to get other suggestions.